# sql select from one to many

Tags: sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I got two tables A and B.One to many relationship exists between A and B. A_Id is a foreign key .

```
         Create table A(Id int,Name varchar(50))
         create table B(Id int,A_Id int,Title varchar(50))

        insert into A Values(1,'name1');
        insert into A Values(2,'name2');
        insert into A Values(3,'name3');
        insert into A Values(4,'name4');

        insert into B Values(10,1,'title1');
        insert into B Values(11,1,'title5');
        insert into B Values(12,2,'title2');
        insert into B Values(13,2,'title6');
        insert into B Values(14,3,'title3');
```

I need to fetch records from table A and title  from table B for matched record 
. If more than one value exists in table B then I need to select the record with the max Id(table B) .

For example. There are two records in table B for A_Id 1 . I need to select a row from table A and 'title5 ' from table B for matching records.

I tried

```
     SELECT A.*, B.Title FROM A JOIN B ON A.Id = B.A_Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived table that uses `ROW_NUMBER` to enumerate records within `A_Id` partitions:

```
select A.Id, A.Name, B.Title
from A
inner join (
   select A_Id, Title,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A_Id ORDER BY Id DESC) AS rn
   from B
) AS B on A.Id = B.A_Id and B.rn = 1
```

The record of derived table `B` with `B.rn = 1` is the one having the maximum `Id` value within its partition and is the one being used in the `INNER JOIN` operation.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce67b/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33dbfe/4)

```
select A.Id, A.Name,b.title
from A
inner join (
   select A_Id, max(id) as id
   from B group by A_Id
) AS c on A.Id = c.A_Id 
inner join b  on b.id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be too performance effective, but surely works :)

SELECT a.*, b.title
FROM   a,b
where a.id=b.a_id
and b.id = (select max(b.id) from b where A_Id=a.id)